# I made a linux distribution (kind of). How can I get it on servers and mirrors?

Tags: distributions

I made this thing called [DH-USB](https://github.com/DH-Box/dh-usb), which is just a custom configuration of Arch made to be installed on (and run entirely from) USB drives. It's not shipped as a live ISO, since live systems didn't seem to have the persistence I needed, but just a .zip file of an .img file. At the moment I have it being served over BitTorrent with a seedbox, but that doesn't always seem to work reliably. Are there public repositories for Linux distributions where I can put this thing and have it be served reliably? I don't want to use SourceForge because of all the controversy.

Comment: renting a web hosting service is quite cheap. BTW, I'm not sure you'll get a lot of success (i.e. downloads)